# SAML IDP in Laravel - Logging out

Tags: php, laravel, saml

I have a Laravel application where users can access a third party application via my application (acting as an Identity Provider).

The logging in was achieved by taking inspiration from: https://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-make-Response/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Saml;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use CodeGreenCreative\SamlIdp\Traits\PerformsSingleSignOn;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use PerformsSingleSignOn;

    /**
     * Initialise a new constructotr instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('verified');
        $this->middleware('investor.eligible');

        $this->init();
    }

    /**
     * Display the login form for accessing SAML
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('user.custodian');
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to log into a given Service Provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $this->setDestination();

        return $this->samlResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Send a SAML message to the intended Service Provider with security assertions and other bearer assertions.
     * In this case we're explicitly sending email and name id
     *
     * @link https://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-make-Response/
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function samlResponse()
    {
        // Create a new SAML Response instance
        $this->response = new \LightSaml\Model\Protocol\Response();

        // Create a response object that we'll send later.
        $this->response
            ->addAssertion($assertion = new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Assertion())
            ->setStatus(
                new \LightSaml\Model\Protocol\Status(
                    new \LightSaml\Model\Protocol\StatusCode(
                        \LightSaml\SamlConstants::STATUS_SUCCESS
                    )
                )
            )
            ->setID(\LightSaml\Helper::generateID())
            ->setIssueInstant(new \DateTime())
            ->setDestination($this->destination)
            ->setIssuer(new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Issuer($this->issuer));

        // Build out our Assertion instance
        $assertion
            ->setId(\LightSaml\Helper::generateID())
            ->setIssueInstant(new \DateTime())
            ->setIssuer(new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Issuer($this->issuer))
            ->setSignature(new \LightSaml\Model\XmlDSig\SignatureWriter($this->certificate, $this->private_key))
            ->setSubject(
                (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Subject())
                    ->setNameID(new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\NameID(
                        auth()->user()->email,
                        \LightSaml\SamlConstants::NAME_ID_FORMAT_EMAIL
                    ))
                    ->addSubjectConfirmation(
                        (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\SubjectConfirmation())
                            ->setMethod(\LightSaml\SamlConstants::CONFIRMATION_METHOD_BEARER)
                            ->setSubjectConfirmationData(
                                (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\SubjectConfirmationData())
                                    ->setNotOnOrAfter(new \DateTime('+1 MINUTE'))
                                    ->setRecipient($this->destination)
                            )
                    )
            )
            ->setConditions(
                (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Conditions())
                    ->setNotBefore(new \DateTime())
                    ->setNotOnOrAfter(new \DateTime('+1 MINUTE'))
                    ->addItem(
                        new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\AudienceRestriction([$this->destination])
                    )
            )
            ->addItem(
                (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\AttributeStatement())
                    ->addAttribute(new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Attribute(
                        \LightSaml\ClaimTypes::EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                        auth()->user()->email,
                    ))
                    ->addAttribute(new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Attribute(
                        \LightSaml\ClaimTypes::NAME_ID,
                        auth()->user()->id,
                    ))
            )
            ->addItem(
                (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\AuthnStatement())
                    ->setAuthnInstant(new \DateTime('-10 MINUTE'))
                    ->setSessionIndex(\LightSaml\Helper::generateID())
                    ->setAuthnContext(
                        (new \LightSaml\Model\Assertion\AuthnContext())
                            ->setAuthnContextClassRef(\LightSaml\SamlConstants::AUTHN_CONTEXT_WINDOWS)
                    )
            );

        return $this->sendSAMLResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Send a SAML response to the Service Provider and display the end result to the user.
     * If this is successful it should log the user into the SP.
     *
     * @param \LightSaml\Model\Protocol\Response $response
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendSAMLResponse()
    {
        $bindingFactory = new \LightSaml\Binding\BindingFactory();
        $postBinding = $bindingFactory->create(\LightSaml\SamlConstants::BINDING_SAML2_HTTP_POST);
        $messageContext = new \LightSaml\Context\Profile\MessageContext();
        $messageContext->setMessage($this->response)->asResponse();
        $httpResponse = $postBinding->send($messageContext);

        return $httpResponse->getContent();
    }

    /**
     * Set the destination.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setDestination()
    {
        $destination = config('samlidp.sp.aHR0cHM6Ly9zZXJ2aWNlcy11ay5zdW5nYXJkZHguY29tL1NpbmdsZVNpZ25Pbi9TZXJ2aWNlUHJvdmlkZXI=.destination');

        $this->destination = $destination;
    }
}
```

I run into a snag however when I try to perform a SAML Single Log Out from an SP.

The steps are as follows:

1. SP sends a logout request
2. IDP responds

So I have a logout controller similar to the above.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Saml;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Jobs\SamlSlo as JobsSamlSlo;
use CodeGreenCreative\SamlIdp\Traits\PerformsSingleSignOn;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use LightSaml\Helper;
use LightSaml\Model\Assertion\Issuer;
use LightSaml\Model\Assertion\NameID;
use LightSaml\Model\Context\DeserializationContext;
use LightSaml\Model\Protocol\LogoutRequest;
use LightSaml\SamlConstants;
use Log;

class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    use PerformsSingleSignOn;

    private $sp;

    /**
     * @param [type] $sp [description]
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sp = config('samlidp.sp.aHR0cHM6Ly9zZXJ2aWNlcy11ay5zdW5nYXJkZHguY29tL1NpbmdsZVNpZ25Pbi9TZXJ2aWNlUHJvdmlkZXI=');
        $this->init();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->setDestination();

        $this->setDestination();

        return redirect($this->request());
    }

    /**
     * [request description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function request()
    {
        $this->response = (new LogoutRequest)
            ->setIssuer(new Issuer($this->issuer))
            ->setNameID((new NameID(Helper::generateID(), SamlConstants::NAME_ID_FORMAT_TRANSIENT)))
            ->setID(Helper::generateID())
            ->setIssueInstant(new \DateTime)
            ->setDestination($this->destination);

        return $this->send(SamlConstants::BINDING_SAML2_HTTP_REDIRECT);
    }

    private function setDestination()
    {
        $destination = $this->sp['logout'];
        $parsed_url = parse_url($destination);
        parse_str($parsed_url['query'] ?? '', $parsed_query_params);
        $parsed_query_params['idp'] = config('app.url');

        $this->destination = strtok($destination, '?') . '?' . http_build_query($parsed_query_params);

        Log::info($this->destination);
    }


}
```

The main issue is that in every example I've seen, the SPs have a dedicated logging out URL.

If I set the logout URL as a route within my IDP would this flow still work?